# How do I correlate build configurations in dependant vcproj files with different names?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, configuration, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution file that requires a third party library (open source).  The containing solution uses the typical configuration names of "Debug" and "Release".

The third-party one has debug and release configurations for both DLL and static libraries - their names are not "Debug" and "Release".

How do I tell the solution to build the dependency first and how do I correlate which configuration to the dependent configuration?

That is, `MyProject:Debug` should build either `3rdParty:debug_shared` or `3rdParty:debug_static`.

UPDATE:

I do not wish to correlate from one to many.  I just want to be able to pick one and stick with it.  So in my case I would correlate Debug in the main project to `3rdParty:shared_debug`.

How do I do that?

When I say build for the solution for debug I want the third-party stuff to build as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDE there is "configuration manager" where you can stick project configurations with solution configurations. Also there is "build dependencies" tool to choose which project should be compiled first.

Comment: I know about the depende ncy order - not sure how to correlate with config names that are different.  I will look at it.  thanks

Comment: I'm not having access to VS now, I can only remember that the "configuration editor" can be access from drop-down list that you use to switch configurations (on the toolbar)

Comment: Thank you both for the answers.  That was it.  Not sure why I never saw that before.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an easy way to have a single solution configuration switch between building different project configurations; if I understand correctly, you want

```
mySolution:debug -> myProject:debug, 3rdParty:debug_shared, ...
```

and at another point in time

```
mySolution:debug -> myProject:debug, 3rdParty:debug_static, ...
```

You could manually or even via macros change the build configuration for the solution each time you build, but isn't that a bit tedious?

If you follow the Visual Studio way, you create extra solution configurations, and change the settings in the build Configuration Manager to have them match to the third-part ones.

```
mySolution:debug_shared -> myProject:debug, 3rdParty:debug_shared, ...
mySolution:debug_static -> myProject:debug, 3rdParty:debug_static, ...
```

This does not change your own project's configuration in any way, and it's relatively easy to switch between them.

**Edit**: if your project depends on this third-party library, then shouldn't it also need two configurations? Suppose your project wants to use the third-party static library, then the linker needs to know its name and path. On the other hand if you want to use the DLL, the linker needs to know another name/path. How do you switch between these two without having two configurations? At some point you'll have to instruct the linker which library to use, so you'll just end up with something like

```
mySolution:debug_shared -> myProject:debug_using_shared_3rdparty, 3rdParty:debug_shared, ...
mySolution:debug_static -> myProject:debug_using_static_3rdparty, 3rdParty:debug_static, ...
```

Comment: Ah, no - I just need to correlate to one of either shared or debug.  THose were just used as examples.  I will correct the question

Comment: I just want to know how to correlate my DEBUG tothe 3rd partyshared_debug and my release to the 3rd party shared_release

Comment: in that case, right-click on the soltion and select 'Configuration Manager'